# Placing stove in center of island or on an edge

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, stove-top

I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct place to post this question since it does border somewhat on decorating, but I'm looking for a more inclusive answer rather then just 'does it look good'.

I'm having an island put in as part of a kitchen remodel. The island is going to be about 54 inches wide by 48 inches long with a 30 inch wide stove in it. Which leaves us a total 24 inches of counter space left over. I'm trying to decide if the stove should go in the middle or off to the side. Off to the side I think is more practical since i think it's more functional to have 2 feet of space on one side of the stove vs 1 foot of space on both sides.

Just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this? I need to make a decision relatively soon - few days at most.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtPir.jpg here's a link to the current proposed layout

thanks

Comment: For clarity - is this for a stove-top (i.e. standalone stove-top mounted in the worktop) or for a free-standing stove?

Comment: Looking at the plan makes me think I should really do freelance kitchen design... I would have suggested a bit of a different layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although most answers to this question may be only opinion-based, which will likely cause the question to be closed due to being "Off-Topic"... I designed kitchens for 11-years and I would lay this out with the range somewhat centered strictly for safety reasons. I recommend not placing a range at the end of a run to prevent a hot pan/pot from being knocked off the stove if the handle is hanging over the edge.

You wouldn't necessarily have to split the difference, though. It would also be sufficient to have a 9" (pullout or tray-base) and a 15" (drawer base) or a 6" (spice cabinet) and a 18" (drawer or door base).

I'm also assuming that the size of the island is so small because it is accommodating sufficient space around the island? So, my sidebar suggestion is: make sure there is at least 42" between the island and anything else.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks  i appreciate your opinion. The cabinets have already been ordered and have arrived so changing cabinets at this point isnt really am option.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the safety issue. I have a 10-12" counter between my range and a doorway, and even with that small amount of buffer I worry about my kids running past that close to the stove.

Answer (score 3):

It is a question I deal with all the time as when I tear down walls between a kitchen and dining room I often add an island.  The answer is really simple for this.  The stove goes in the middle.  You need to find 12 inch cabinets.

There are two issues here.  First the sides of ovens look crappy.  Makers don't spend time on the sides so you don't want it showing.  Second is if you hide the side with a wall then how do you construct this, what sort of countertop goes on top of the wall... it is just odd.

First I have run across almost your exact use case before but I generally would tend to not try to put a stove on an island that small.  But you can still do it and it can look really nice.  You will need to buy a slide in oven.  Run the countertop full length with the over cut out - so you should have counter behind oven.  Let the counter overhang on the sides a couple inches to provide prep space - 15" is a good amount of space.

For your 12" cabinets get a drawer one cabinet combo and put in full width shelving that pulls out all the way.  The right pull-out shelving can make a 12" cabinet very functional.

Comment: In the past we usually put a cook top in then a wall mount oven , it will cost a bit more but look much nicer and not as much space is wasted as there is a huge amount of wasted space in a stove/oven combo just something to think of since you are doing a complete remodel (I believe this is what DMore may be saying with the slide in oven)

Comment: Why does a slide in waste more space?  It's a little too late though to change that as the cabinets have already arrived and are just waiting to be installed.

Comment: Oh and there will be a waterfall down both sides of the island

Comment: @merk - slide-in oven is basically an standard oven without the backlip with the controls (controls are moved to front usually) - not talking about the cooktop.  As for your waterfall I am guessing some stone?   If some I wouldn't put a stone right next to an oven.  First it will never look right.  Second the heat from the oven could damage or break the stone.

Comment: another reason is it's nice to have space for prep on both sides when preparing food. It's not the best to chop with only a foot of space, but it's plenty to i.e. have ingredients in bowls, set spoons/spatulas down, hold plates to serve food onto, etc.

Comment: There is a safety issue with a cooktop/oven on the edge of an island. If it was right on the corner, then there is a good chance that a person would bump up against the range and get burned. For the record, I am not a big fan of having a cooktop in an island. I would probably never design a kitchen with one. It adds a lot of unnecessary cost to a project.  Since they need to be vented, you either have a choice of an obtrusive vent coming down from the ceiling, or getting an expensive downdraft system.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson - I have been in 100 kitchens where the stove was the first thing next to the door or whatever.  There is no code behind this safety concern.  But you are right.  I usually just try to let islands be islands.  Putting a sink or oven is fine if you are out of space but it takes away from the function of the island.  We eat dinner at mine and play poker there.  Not sure that works with an oven.